# Is jQuery.trim() deprecated?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per jQuery 3.5 documentation, [jQuery.trim() is deprecated.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)

But when I try to use it with jQuery 3.5 it's still working. Should I replace it with the native [String#trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) function immediately, or can I still use jQuery trim for a while?

Comment: Deprecated means it's a warning it will be removed in the future, it does not mean it was removed now.

Comment: And to answer your question, yes you should use the native function.

Comment: [String.trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) works on all useful browsers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) does not mean removed, it means that in a future version there is no guarantee that this method will still exist.

As per the [jquery trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) docs:

> Note: This API has been deprecated in jQuery 3.5; please use the native String.prototype.trim method instead.

Docs for [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is depreciated but the suggested replacement of `String.prototype.trim()` can cause issues since it makes the assumption that the object is already a string.

I chose to define the following and turn all calls of `$.trim(object)` into `String.trim(object)`.

```
String.trim = String.trim || function (value) {
    if (value === null)
        return '';
    else
        return String(value).trim();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears that there is a change in how this function is now being called. For codes using jQuery 3.5 and below, the usual function call works:

```
let xString = " This is my string with spaces  ";
let xTrimmed = xString.trim();
```

But for codes using jQuery 3.5 upwards:

```
let xString = " This is my string with spaces  ";
let xTrimmed = $.trim(xString);
```

**Edit:**

It appears that jQuery as gone back to its original method: **xString.trim();** try any of the two that works.

Comment: refer to the documentation @Jamiec posted in their answer. the above answer is backwards. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: Noted; unfortunately, both reference links report error 523: Origin is unreachable, it maybe a temporary issue - I will check again.